# Erro ao acessar "Java Build Path" no Eclipse

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Quando tento acessar *MEU_PROJETO_ANDROID - Properties - Java Build Path*, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> the currently displayed page contains invalid values

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo *AndroidManifest.xml* está assim:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

E não consigo importar nenhum projeto Android para o Eclipse, sempre aparece a seguinte:

> Invalid project description

Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde pode ser o problema?

Comment: Vê se essas 2 perguntas do SOen te ajudam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784652/eclipse-invalid-project-description-when-creating-new-project-from-existing-so e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311474/problem-importing-android-project-archives-into-eclipse.

Comment: Quando tentei importar novamente, com outro nome, tive o mesmo erro... E o mesmo erro persiste em todas as outras tentativas também.

Comment: PS.: Tenho uma certa dificuldade com tópicos em inglês.. Demoro para traduzir e muita das vezes perco informações importantes no translate da Google.
Eu até pesquisei em muitos tópicos, em inglês, que continham o erro "the currently displayed page contains invalid values", mas ainda nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta iniciar o Eclipse pelo cmd/terminal com a opção `-clean`

No Windows:

```
 Eclipse.exe -clean
```

No Linux:

```
./eclipse -clean
```

ou se Eclipse está na sua PATH

```
eclipse -clean
```

Isto irá limpar o cache de plug-ins, talvez ele resolve o problema.

Fonte: [StackOverFlow EUA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776334/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface-when-usin/3492924#3492924)